# Len Function to find a Mid?

Tags: string, function, ms-access, vba

I am trying to pull out a piece of a string to no avail.

> string = 90-8566-Doe-20140317_122627T-2_Update.pdf

I want to pull out the "Doe portion"

I have been using a Mid function with a Len function component and it just isn't coming out right.

Comment: How do you know where the Doe section is?  Is it always after the second - or does it always start in the same place?  If you can rely on the hyphens, then split it into an array (by hyphen) and you section is the 3rd element

Comment: I can always rely on the hyphens. The first 8 characters/numbers will always be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming first 8 characters are always the same:

```
=MID($A$1,9,FIND("-",$A$1,9)-9)
```

Or in VBA:

```
Range("A2") = Mid(Range("A1"), 9, InStr(9, Range("A1"), "-") - 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the array by the hyphen character.

Then your value is the 3rd value in the array.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with arrays. How would I split it?

Comment: Well actually I'm not overly familiar with VBA.  For VB check this out:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

I assume it's the same or similar